# What's wrong with casting 0.0 to double?

Tags: c#, casting, .net

I have `InvalidCastException` when I try to cast 0.0 to double, why is that so? It's fine when I do `(float)value` instead.

[image]

Comment: Any more detail about the object `value`? (in particular its actual type).

Comment: Check out Eric Lippert's blog-post on this subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: Is there a reason why you seem to be reinventing the wheel?  .NET already has a class that allows you to convert objects from one type to another.

Comment: @tvanfosson, this is actually a WPF converter to display float values as integers, I don't like to reinvent the wheel too. Is there anyway to display a float/double as an int without decimal places? That's what I am trying to achieve here

Comment: @jiewmeng - that makes more sense -- just use Convert.ToInt32() or Convert.ToInt64(), though, internally and avoid the issue.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In general, when you put a value type into an `object` (called *boxing*) you need to *unbox* it to the *exact same* value type. You cannot do a conversion to another type instead. This is what happens here.

If you really want to convert the object, you *first* need to unbox it. Say your original value was a `float` before you boxed it in an `object`:

```
double d = (double) (float) value;
```

Or use the method proposed by others, which uses `Convert`. This has the advantage that the original type doesn’t have to be known.

Comment: I'd warn that using `Convert` is not equivalent to the above double casting, since if the converted object happens to be `null`, `Convert` will silently return zero, while the double casting will fail on the first cast, as you would expect to happen from any non-float value, such as `null`. Remember, `null` isn't `0`, but it is with `Convert`.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek Considering that `default double` is `0`, and `default <reference-type>` is `null`, `Convert` is roughly equivalent to the so-called safe-cast `as` operator, although it isn't quite as safe.

Comment: @jpaugh How is that equivalent? You can't use the `as` operator to safe-cast something that can be null to `double`. It won't even compile. There is no equivalence between `0` and `null` in the language.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek I should have said analogous, instead of "roughly equivalent." They perform a similar operation (converting types), but for different "kinds" of types (`Convert` for numerics, and `as` for reference types).

Comment: For that matter, they are actually *equally* safe: if the result of `Convert` (or `as`) is `0` (or `null`), then you can't be sure whether the original value was `0` (`null`).

Answer (score 10):

That's normal. If the object type is `float` you cannot cast it to `double` because they are not of the same type:

```
object o = 1.0f;
double d = (double)o; // will throw an exception
```

You need to convert it:

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(o);
```

Comment: What are you talking about?! So you cannot do this?    float f = 0.0f;
                double d = (double)f;

Comment: @Aliostad, you can do that. You cannot do what I showed in my answer: cast an object (whose type is float) to double which is what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: your explanation is confusing because you fail to distinguish between the underlying object type (float) and the variable type (object) and mention boxing explicitly.  As @Aliostad notes, it could be interpreted to mean that you can't upcast a float (unboxed) to a double, which is plainly false.

Comment: Please make a reference to boxing. double d is also an object.

Answer (score 4):

The float has been boxed as an object. So you're trying to convert a boxed float into a double. Use Vyas's convert instead - it is far more flexible and should always do the right thing:

```
var val=Convert.ToDouble(value);
```

Comment: So `(double)((float)value)` would work, as it's properly unboxed before the `double` cast ?

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
var val=Convert.ToDouble(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot cast an arbitrary object to `double`.