# why doesn't std::any_cast support implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, c++17

Why does `std::any_cast` throw a `std::bad_any_cast` exception when an implicit conversion from the actual stored type to the requested type would be possible?

For example:

```
std::any a = 10;  // holds an int now
auto b = std::any_cast<long>(a);   // throws bad_any_cast exception
```

Why is this not allowed and is there a workaround to allow an implicit conversion (in case the exact type that `std::any` holds is unknown)?

Comment: It’s neither possible *nor necessary*! In fact, [other languages have the exact same restriction for unboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113084/1968). I can’t think of a single scenario where this is problematic.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`std::any_cast` is specified in terms of `typeid`. To quote [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) on this:

> Throws `std::bad_any_cast` if the `typeid` of the requested `ValueType` does
>   not match that of the contents of operand.

Since [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) doesn't allow the implementation to "figure out" an implicit conversion is possible, there's no way (to my knowledge) that `any_cast` can know it's possible either.

To put it otherwise, the type erasure provided by `std::any` relies on information available only at run-time. And that information is not quite as rich as the information the compiler has for figuring out conversions. That's the cost of type erasure in C++17.

Comment: Ok that makes sense if it's linked to typeid and if I understand your edit, it is not possible to do a workaround without knowing the exact type?

Comment: @Timo - Is it not possible? If you have an idea how, it'd be a major breakthrough. I'm not aware of a workaround. To even attempt the conversion, you need to obtain a reference of the correct type to the erased object. But to obtain it, you need to know the type (statically) beforehand. It's a chicken and egg problem, the more you think about it. C++ doesn't support anything of the sort currently.

Comment: It is certainly possible to create a `std::any` with a wider contract. For example, any derived-to-base or cross-cast could be handled based on `dynamic_cast` facilities and any primitive conversion could be hard-coded. Whereas this is *desirable* is a whole other matter, however, most notably because it would not be as cheap. as just checking a `typeid`.

Comment: @MFH: I have no idea what brought that observation... If you cannot imagine how to use `dynamic_cast` here, I invite you to inform yourself on type-erasure techniques. For example, how does `shared_ptr<void>` knows how to delete the underlying value? If you can answer this question, then you should be able to work out how to use `dynamic_cast` inside an `any` implementation.

Comment: @MatthieuM. the implementation I can think of would require a templated virtual function, which isn't possible.

Comment: @Simple: There's a short-cut in my last comment that may be throwing you off, sorry; in this first comment I mentioned *facilities*. That is, the mechanism underlying the implementation of `dynamic_cast` has the ability to go from source to destination pointer without templated code. See https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/dyncast.cc for an example implementation.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Have you actually inspected the code you linked? Because it is bound to fail when your void * does not refer to a polymorphic type! So unless you want to force additional overhead (like std::function) onto every user of std::any it is not possible to do that cast!

Comment: @MFH: Yes, `dynamic_cast` only ever works on polymorphic types. When *storing* a value, you statically know whether it is polymorphic or not, whether it's a primitive or not, etc... at this point you can therefore apply type-erasures techniques to encode the appropriate knowledge in a v-table (instead of storing a `typeid`), that is, implement an appropriate strategy. For a primitive, it'll allow cross-casting to a fixed list of other primitives. For a polymorphic value, it can leverage RTTI information like `dynamic_cast` does. Simple, workable, little overhead over the current approach.

Comment: @MatthieuM. So, just as I said: You're forcing everybody to pay the price of a vtable-call which goes against the basic tenets of C++ and is especially inappropriate for a "vocabulary" type. Furthermore: your cross-casting would not work for any_casts to primitive references...

Comment: @MFH: No I am not. You can have two methods, one for exact types and for cross-casts. The exact type just compare virtual pointers, which is just as expensive as comparing typeid. As for primitives, I already mentioned you'd need different strategies.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You shouldn't have two ways to extract the data as any_cast is designed to mimic a C++-cast. Anyway *you're right* - I overlooked the requirement for deep copies which makes vtables already necessary for std::any, so yeah adding a broader casting support would be possible (albeit the problem of dangling references would be magnified by this feature)

Answer (score 21):

To do what you want you'd need full code reflection and reification.  That means every detail of every type would have to be saved to every binary (and every signature of every function on every type!  And every template anywhere!), and when you ask to convert from an any to a type X you'd pass the data about X into the any, which would contain enough information about the type it contained to basically attempt to compile a conversion to X and fail or not.

There are languages that can do this; every binary ships with IR bytecode (or raw source) and an interpreter/compiler.  These languages tend to be 2x or more slower than C++ at most tasks and have significantly larger memory footprints.  It may be possible to have those features without that cost, but nobody has that language that I know of.

C++ doesn't have this ability.  Instead, it forgets almost all facts about types during compilation.  For any, it remembers a typeid which it can be used to get an exact match, and how to convert its storage to said exact match.

Comment: Languages that do this typically use JIT compilation to achieve speeds comparable to C++. The nice thing about C++ (and rust etc) is that they are predictable and deterministic (to the machine, not the developer - if you don't have undefined behavior) and strict - not doing GC means you have strictly more control over allocations for example.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I agree: a factor of 2 is "comparable".  It may be possible to write a language that does all of the above and doesn't have a ~2x slowdown, but I have yet to meet it.  And I understand that JIT can handle some microbenchmarks and match C++ speed in certain cases.  Possibly it is just the near uniform use of GC in JIT languages that is the real slowdown, and a JIT langauge without GC could handle full codebase reflection/reification without the performance hit.  Please point me at that language, I'd love to look at it.

Answer (score 6):

`std::any` *has* to be implemented with type-erasure. That's because it can store *any* type and can't be a template. There is just no other functionality in C++ to achieve this at the moment.

What that means is that `std::any` will store a type-erased pointer, `void*` and `std::any_cast` will convert that pointer to the specified type and that's it. It just does a sanity check using `typeid` before to check whether you the type you cast it to is the one stored into the any.

Allowing implicit conversions would be impossible using the current implementation. Think about it (ignore the `typeid` check for now).

```
std::any_cast<long>(a);
```

`a` stores an `int` and not a `long`. How should `std::any` know that? It can just cast its `void*` to the type specified, dereference it and return it. Casting a pointer from one type to another is a strict aliasing violation and results in UB, so that's a bad idea.

`std::any` would have to store the actual type of the object stored in it, which is not possible. You can't store types in C++ right now. It could maintain a list of types along with their respective `typeid`s and switch over them to get the current type and perform the implicit conversion. But there is no way to do that for *every* single type that you are going to use. User defined types wouldn't work anyways, and you'd have to rely on things such as macros to "register" your type and generate the appropriate switch case for it<sup>1</sup>.

Maybe something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T any_cast(const any &Any) {
  const auto Typeid = Any.typeid();
  if (Typeid == typeid(int))
    return *static_cast<int *>(Any.ptr());
  else if (Typeid == typeid(long))
    return *static_cast<long *>(Any.ptr());
  // and so on. Add your macro magic here.

  // What should happen if a type is not registered?
}
```

Is this a good solution? No, by far. The switch is costly, and C++'s mantra is "you don't pay for what you don't use" so no, there is no way of achieving this currently. The approach is also "hacky" and very brittle (what happens if you forget to register a type). In short, the possible benefits of doing something like this is not worth the trouble in the first place.

> is there a workaround to allow an implicit conversion (in case the exact type that std::any holds is unknown)?

Yes, implement `std::any` (or a comparable type) and `std::any_cast` yourself using the macro register approach mentioned above<sup>1</sup>. I won't recommend it though. If you don't and can't know what type `std::any` stores and need to access it, you have a possible design flaw.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Don't actually know if this is possible, I'm not that good in macro (ab)use. You can also hard-code your types in for your custom implementation or use a separate tool for it.

Comment: That sort of casting trickery with registration is certainly possible.  I've done it.  But the resulting code is most definitely *not* the kind of code you would expect to find in a standard language feature.  It looks more like a special domain-specific function (which is exactly what it was when I implemented it)

Answer (score 1):

This could be implemented by trying a contingency implicit conversion, if the type id of the requested type was not the same as the type id of the stored type. But it would involve a cost and hence violate the ["not pay for what you don't use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304992/how-can-i-better-learn-to-not-pay-for-what-you-dont-use) principle. Another `any` shortcoming, for example, is the inability to store an array.

```
std::any("blabla");
```

will work, but it will store a `char const*`, not an array. You could add such a feature in your own customized `any`, but then you'd need to store a pointer to a string literal by doing:

```
any(&*"blabla");
```

which is kind of odd. The decisions of the Standard committee are a compromise and never satisfy everyone, but you fortunately have the option of implementing your own `any`.

You could also extend `any` to store and then invoke type-erased [functors](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/callback.cpp), for example, but this is also not supported by the Standard.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not well posed; implicit conversion to the right type are *in principle* possible, but disabled.
This restriction probably exists to maintain a certain level of safety or to mimic the explict cast necessary (through pointer) in the C-version of `any` (`void*`).
(The example implementation below shows that it is possible.)

Having said that, your target code still doesn't work because you need to know the exact type before conversion, but this can *in principle* work:

```
any a = 10;  // holds an int now
long b = int(a); // possible but today's it needs to be: long b = any_cast<int>(a);
```

To show that implicit conversions are *technically* possible (but can fail at runtime):

```
#include<boost/any.hpp>

struct myany : boost::any{
    using boost::any::any;
    template<class T> operator T() const{return boost::any_cast<T>(*this);}
};

int main(){

    boost::any ba = 10;
//  int bai = ba; // error, no implicit conversion

    myany ma = 10; // literal 10 is an int
    int mai = ma; // implicit conversion is possible, other target types will fail (with an exception)
    assert(mai == 10);

    ma = std::string{"hello"};
    std::string mas = ma;
    assert( mas == "hello" );
 }
```