# Is there a way to simultaneously assign a type to multiple templates in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, type-erasure

This question is based on the example code below, which is inspired by [Sean Parent's talk](http://sean-parent.stlab.cc/papers-and-presentations/#inheritance-is-the-base-class-of-evil).
The goal of the code below is to provide an object wrapper similar to [boost::any](https://github.com/boostorg/any/blob/develop/include/boost/any.hpp#L247:36). I wrote this code to educate myself of type erasure. So, there is no practical uses this code intends (considering there is already boost::any).

```
class ObjWrap {
public:
  template <typename T>
  ObjWrap(T O) : Self(new Obj<T>(std::move(O))) {}

  template <typename T>
  friend typename T * getObjPtr(ObjWrap O) {
    return static_cast<T*>(O.Self->getObjPtr_());
  }
private:
  struct Concept {
    virtual ~Concept() = 0;
    virtual void* getObjPtr_() = 0;
  };
  template <typename T>
  struct Obj : Concept {
    Obj(T O) : Data(std::move(O)) {}
    void* getObjPtr_() { return static_cast<void*>(&Data); }

    T Data;
  };

  std::unique_ptr<Concept> Self;
};
```

Before I can really ask my question, let's examine the code in the following aspects:

1. `Concept::getObjPtr_` returns `void*` because a) `Concept` cannot be a template otherwise `unique_ptr<Concept> Self` would not work; b) `void*` is the only way I know how to return `Obj::Data` in a type-agnostic way in C++. Please correct me if this is wrong...
2. `T * getObjPtr(ObjWrap O)` is a template that needs instantiation separately from the `ObjWrap` constructor.
3. The use of `ObjWrap` basically includes: a) make a new `ObjWrap` over an existing object; b) retrieve the underlying object given an `ObjWrap`. For example:

   ```
   ObjWrap a(1);
   ObjWrap b(std::string("b"));
   int* p_a = getObjPtr<int>(a);
   std::string* p_b = getObjPtr<std::string>(b);
   ```

This works but it is obvious that `getObjPtr<int>(b)` does not work as intended.

**So, my question is:**

Is there a way to fix the above code so that we can simply use `int* p_a = getObjPtr(a)` and `std::string* p_b = getObjPtr(b)` or better yet `auto p_a = getObjPtr(a)` and `auto p_b = getObjPtr(b)`? In other words, is there a way in C++ to instantiate two templates at the same time (if so, we can instantiate the `ObjWrap` constructor and `T* getObjPtr(ObjWrap)` at compile time of a `ObjWrap` object, e.g., `ObjWrap a(1)`)?

**Edit 1:**

Making ObjWrap a templated class does not help since it defeats the purpose of type erasure.

```
template <typename T>
class ObjWrap {
  /* ... */
};

ObjWrap<int> a(1); // this is no good for type erasure.
```

**Edit 2:**

I was reading the code and realize that it can be modified to reflect the idea a little better. So, please also look at the following code:

```
class ObjWrap {
public:
  template <typename T>
  ObjWrap(T O) : Self(new Obj<T>(std::move(O))) {}

  template <typename T>
  T * getObjPtr() {
    return static_cast<T*>(Self->getObjPtr_());
  }
private:
  struct Concept {
    virtual ~Concept() = 0;
    virtual void* getObjPtr_() = 0;
  };
  template <typename T>
  struct Obj : Concept {
    Obj(T O) : Data(std::move(O)) {}
    void* getObjPtr_() { return static_cast<void*>(&Data); }

    T Data;
  };

  std::unique_ptr<Concept> Self;
};

int main() {
  ObjWrap a(1);
  ObjWrap b(std::string("b"));
  int* p_a = a.getObjPtr<int>();
  std::string* p_b = b.getObjPtr<std::string>();

  std::cout << *p_a << " " << *p_b << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

The main difference between this version of the code versus the one above is that `T * getObjPtr()` is a member function that is encapsulated by the `ObjWrap` object.

**Edit 3:**

My question regarding type erasure is answered by accepted answer. However, the question on simultaneous type instantiation to multiple templates is yet to be answered. My guess is currently C++ does not allow it but it would be nice to hear from people with more experience on that.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ was just about to post an answer which addresses the OP's real question. Please re-open.

Comment: You should not add more and more code to a question based on re-readings. This is not how the site is supposed to be used.

Comment: @einpoklum Sorry about that. I thought it might be fine since it is essentially the same code and it may be interesting to see them both on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that may help.

First thing to say is that if Obj ever needs to expose the address of the object, it's not Sean Parent's 'inheritance is the root of all evil' type-erasing container.

The trick is to ensure that the interface of Obj offers all semantic actions and queries the wrapper will ever need.

In order to provide this, it's often a reasonable idea to cache the address of the object and its `type_id` in the concept.

Consider the following updated example, in which there is one public method - operator==. The rule is that two Objs are equal if they contain the same type of object and those objects compare equal.

Note that the address and type_id:

1) are implementation details and not exposed on the interface of Obj

2) are accessible without virtual calls, which short-circuits the not-equal case.

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

class ObjWrap 
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    ObjWrap(T O) : Self(new Model<T>(std::move(O))) {}

    // objects are equal if they contain the same type of model
    // and the models compare equal
    bool operator==(ObjWrap const& other) const
    {
        // note the short-circuit when the types are not the same
        // this means is_equal can guarantee that the address can be cast
        // without a further check
        return Self->info == other.Self->info
        && Self->is_equal(other.Self->addr);
    }

    bool operator!=(ObjWrap const& other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ObjWrap const& o)
    {
        return o.Self->emit(os);
    }

private:
    struct Concept 
    {
        // cache the address and type here in the concept.
        void* addr;
        std::type_info const& info;

        Concept(void* address, std::type_info const& info)
        : addr(address)
        , info(info)
        {}

        virtual ~Concept() = default;

        // this is the concept's interface    
        virtual bool is_equal(void const* other_address) const = 0;
        virtual std::ostream& emit(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct Model : Concept 
    {
        Model(T O) 
        : Concept(std::addressof(Data), typeid(T))
        , Data(std::move(O)) {}

        // no need to check the pointer before casting it.
        // Obj takes care of that
        /// @pre other_address is a valid pointer to a T    
        bool is_equal(void const* other_address) const override
        {
            return Data == *(static_cast<T const*>(other_address));
        }

        std::ostream& emit(std::ostream& os) const override
        {
            return os << Data;
        }

        T Data;
    };


std::unique_ptr<Concept> Self;
};


int main()
{
    auto x = ObjWrap(std::string("foo"));
    auto y = ObjWrap(std::string("foo"));
    auto z = ObjWrap(int(2));

    assert(x == y);
    assert(y != z);

    std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcece2a824a42948

Comment: "First thing to say is that if Obj ever needs to expose the address of the object, it's not Sean Parent's 'inheritance is the root of all evil' type-erasing container." thanks for pointing that out. You are right. My code is trying to behave like boost::any and I was wondering if there is a more type-erasing way than what boost::any is using.

Comment: @BigHead yes. If you want to query for a given type make get() return a boost::optional<T&>. Note that you can still make use of the cached type_Id and address.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. (etc. etc.) Please correct me if this is wrong...

Your premise is wrong at least in principle, if not also in practice. You're insisting on making `getObjPtr()` a virtual method, and using an abstract base class. But - you've not established this is necessary. Remember - using virtual methods is expensive! Why should I pay for virtuals just to get type erasure?

> Is there a way to fix the above code so that we can simply use `int* p_a = getObjPtr(a)`

Take Sean Parent's talk title to heart (as opposed to the fact that he does use inheritance in the talk), drop the inheritance and the answer should be Yes. **Edit:** It's sufficient for the code that erases the type and the code that un-erases the type to know what the type is - as long as you don't need to *act* on the type-erased data in a type-specific way. In Sean Parent's talk, you need to be able to make non-trivial copies of it, to move it, to draw it etc. With `std::any`/`boost::any` you might need copying and moving, which may require virtuals - but that's the most general use case.

Even `std::any` limits what you can and can't do, as is discussed in this question:

[why doesn't std::any_cast support implicit conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428018/why-doesnt-stdany-cast-support-implicit-conversion)

Comment: But Sean Parent's code presented in the talk uses virtual methods as well... So does boost::any...

Comment: "Why should I pay for virtuals just to get type erasure?" How do you implement type erasure without virtual functions? You can use function pointers, sure, but then you're effectively reimplementing virtual functions.

Comment: "using virtual methods is expensive!"  using virtual methods has a cost.   Whether or not it's "expensive" is situational.