# How do I support any_cast to cast a custom class to a string?

Tags: c++, std, c++17

This question is related to [Type erasing type erasure, `any` questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835747)

Given the class wstr below (just a string wrapper)

```
class wstr {
public:
    std::string text;
};
```

I have an any...

```
std::any myAny({myWstr});
```

..and I want to cast (convert) it to a string..

```
std::string myString = std::any_cast<std::string>(myAny);
```

... Is there a means of doing this by using template specialization, or (as I suspect) is this missing the point of using std::any?

This question is not about implicit conversion. I was thinking that I may need to write a friend function/overloading the cast, similar to writing ostream operator extensions.

Another way of asking this would be: Am I correct in thinking an std::any_cast does NOT CAST to anything, but rather ONLY CASTS a std::any back to it's original form, and therefore one cannot overload a function that supports the cast to eg, std::string, and is not available (for some reason) for friend function overloading / template specialization?

```
wstr myWstr("foo");
std::any myAny({myWstr});
wstr myWstr = std::any_cast<wstr>(myAny); //is okay.
std::string mMytr = std::any_cast<std::string>(myAny); //No overloads!
```

Comment: See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49428018/6205379) on the subject a while back. You cannot any_cast to another type.

Comment: `std::any<wstr>` is wrong, because [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) isn't a template. Are you perhaps thinking about [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why doesn't std::any\_cast support implicit conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428018/why-doesnt-stdany-cast-support-implicit-conversion)

Comment: afaik `any_cast` is not really to cast between different types but merely to access the value stored in the `any` in a typesafe manner

Comment: here are some examples: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: There is some sample code to convert between wide and narrow strings here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210723/how-to-detect-â€-combination-of-unicode-in-c-string/51212415#51212415

Comment: btw I think what you actually need is a conversion not a cast

Comment: It does indeed look like you are missing the point of std::any. What are you trying to achieve exactly? And what do you think std::any does?

Comment: Sorry folks - I have edited the question to be more clear.  This isn't about implicit conversion, but rather I was thinking of function overloading.

Comment: @Timo, No - I am asking a slightly different question. This was more about how to overload / specialise the any_cast function, and did not expect dynamic casting.

Comment: @Konchog: The thing is, you shouldn't *want to* "overload/specialize" `any_cast`. If that's what you want to do, then you are probably using `any` outside of its intended use case and purpose.

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes - normally one wouldn't ever dream of it.  I am using this in a visitor class where I am dealing with tokens after a parse.  The purpose is really just to save from having to test for whitespace (what the wstr is) via type when I want to treat it as text.  It's a bit complex to explain -everything- so I tried (vainly) to put it into a tiny case.  But you are right... of course..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example given for [`any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) at cppreference shows that casting an `int` to a `std::string` results in `bad_any_cast` exception being thrown.

The result will be the same if `any_cast` is used to convert `wstr` to `std::string`.

And BTW, `std::any<wstr> myAny;` does not work, since `std::any` is a class and not a template.

Instead you can test it this way:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

class wstr {
public:
    std::string text;
};

int main()
{
    wstr ws;
    auto a = std::any(ws);

    try {
        std::cout << std::any_cast<std::string>(a) << '\n';
    }
    catch(const std::bad_any_cast& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

See [demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mXhgBMiOFBbpSm54).

Comment: Thanks, but due to the poverty of my initial question, this misses the point.. the point I was making was concerning extending/overloading std::any_cast, not expecting it to do the cast as it stands.

Comment: @Konchog: then you will have to write your own conversion function, constructor or operator. `std::any_cast` is not the way to do it.